# Mysql query to search same column in different tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

table_a

```
 ╔════╦══════╗
 ║ Id ║ MID  ║
 ╠════╬══════╣
 ║  1 ║ 5996 ║
 ║  2 ║  148 ║
 ║  3 ║  101 ║
 ║  4 ║ 5636 ║
 ║  5 ║  143 ║
 ║  6 ║  101 ║
 ║  7 ║  959 ║
 ║  8 ║  148 ║
 ╚════╩══════╝
```

table_b

```
 ╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
 ║ Id ║  Community   ║ MID  ║
 ╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
 ║  1 ║ Jeff Atwood  ║ 5636 ║
 ║  2 ║ Geoff Dalgas ║  148 ║
 ║  3 ║ Neal  Marley ║  101 ║
 ║  4 ║ Joel Spolsky ║  959 ║
 ╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

table_c

```
 ╔════╦══════════════╦══════╗
 ║ Id ║  Community   ║ MID  ║
 ╠════╬══════════════╬══════╣
 ║  1 ║ Jim Atwood   ║ 3212 ║
 ║  2 ║ Rim  Dalgas  ║  428 ║
 ║  3 ║ Jarrod Dixon ║  388 ║
 ║  4 ║ Noel Spolsky ║  339 ║
 ╚════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

I can only use plain Mysql query.
I need to join **table_a** with **table_b** to find the **community** and in case there is no **community** corresponding to the **MID** in **tablea**  I need to join the **table_c** to get **community**.How to Accomplish that?
Please help me.Thank you!

Comment: why do you have 2 similar tables? so you have redundancy in you database

Comment: What is the difference in _structure_ between the data in table b and table c? If that data does not differ in structure, but only in _meaning_ – then you should probably rather use _one_ table for it, with an additional column that can be used to differentiate between data of “type” b or c.

Comment: Two tables are exactly same but from different schools..I cant change the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` with both tables and then select the first existing item using [`COALESCE`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php):

```
SELECT a.Id, a.MID, COALESCE(b.Community, c.Community, '') as Community
FROM table_a a 
    LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.MID = b.MID
    LEFT JOIN table_c c ON a.MID = c.MID
```

In this case if you have matching data in `table_b`, then `b.Community` is used, otherwise if there is matching data in `table_c`, then `c.Community` is used. If there is no match in either of the tables, then empty space is used.